# How do I find out where a specific route goes?

Tags: routing

In once place, I have a /Vendor/Module/etc/routes.xml, showing:

```xml
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="categories" frontName="categories">
            <module name="Vendor_Module" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

which points to a valid (as far as I can see) controller. (Index/Index, to be precisely. )

In the database, table `mg_url_rewrite`, "categories" is pointed towards catalog/product/view/id/.

#### How can I figure out where a request for www.mysite.com/categories *actually* goes?

My instinct says the routes.xml file, but an exact duplicate of that controller in another module shows an empty page, where .../categories actually shows the categories of the webshop. All the controller does is:

```php
public function __construct(Context $context, PageFactory $resultPageFactory)
    {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Categories'));
        return $resultPage;
    }
```

But the page doesn't even have a title, which the other (controller exact duplicate except from namespaces, and same for the routes.xml except ofcourse for the Vendor_Module, route id and frontname) module does.

However, if I manually enter the url provided by the `mg_url_rewrite` table, I get a 404.

Comment: So the actual question is, where to figure out if Magento prefers the routes defined in routes.xml or the rewrites in url_rewrite ?

Comment: Attempted to elaborate a bit more on the case, and why I think neither of those two candidates is actually loaded. Perfect answer would be a failsafe way to figure out where a certain route goes, and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UrlRewrite Module. And so the urlrewrite rules use an additinoal entry inside the routerList. This entry has the sort order of 20.

```
    <type name="Magento\Framework\App\RouterList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="routerList" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="urlrewrite" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\UrlRewrite\Controller\Router</item>
                    <item name="disable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">20</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

This routerlist is traversed inside the `Magento\Framework\App\FrontController`. The first one which matched your route is used.

Before the urlRewrite only the RouterList of the module-robots is used.

So I would guess that url-rewrite takes precendence before routes.xml, but i didn't dig further into it yet.

*edit:
What checks for the routes.xml inside the frontend is not the default router. But the standard router, which is also defined in the module-store di.xml and is located in.
`Magento\Framework\App\Router\Base`. This one has a sort order of 30 and is processed directly after the url-rewrites.

The default router which is also defined in module-store, is only for processing the no-route pages.

Comment: Yes, it seems so from [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/routing.html). But I'm still getting 404's for every rewrite destination in the table, while the `.../categories` request runs fine. What I'm really looking for is A) Some compiled file or B) Something I can run, which shows where Magento is actually going.

Comment: If you have a development system, maybe you can use xdebug to see where Magento is going. Maybe somehow the urlrewrites are disabled or modified by some module ?

Comment: "xdebug" ? Do you have a link about that? It sounds interesting, and exactly like what I'm looking for.

Comment: https://xdebug.org/

Comment: I'll read up on that one. Meanwhile, I'll accept your answer, because I think that for a vast majority of others stumbling upon this question, it'll be the one they need, even if there seems to be something unsanitary going on at the installation I'm working with.